# Repeating vectors in Clojure

Tags: clojure, sequences, playing-cards

I am a Clojure newbie. I am trying to get two copies of a vector of card suits. The non-[DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) way that I can come up with is

```
(def suits [:clubs :diamonds :hearts :spades])
(def two-times (concat suits suits))
```

There must be a more functional way (even if it takes more characters :-)). What if i want N times?  Any suggestions?

All of the things I try, like

```
(replicate 2 suits)
```

results in two separate vectors:

```
([:clubs :diamonds :hearts :spades] [:clubs :diamonds :hearts :spades])
```

How do I "flatten" the structure?

Comment: There's nothing non-functional about using the value of one Var inside the `def` form creating another Var. In fact, that's the natural thing to do if the second Var depends on the first. Of course if you want a general method of concatenating n copies of a seq, where n might or might not be known beforehand, then you do need a better solution (as found in the answers here).

Comment: Actually, that's what I meant (N copies). I agree that my two-times function is "functional" -- it is just not practical if I want 100 copies :-).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`concat` gives you a lazy seq.  If you want to end up with a (non-lazy) vector instead:

```
user> (into suits suits)
[:clubs :diamonds :hearts :spades :clubs :diamonds :hearts :spades]
user> (reduce into (replicate 2 suits))
[:clubs :diamonds :hearts :spades :clubs :diamonds :hearts :spades]
```

Depending whether you're accessing this by index a lot or iterating over it, either a vector or a seq might be more appropriate.

There's always `cycle` too, if you want an endless (lazy) stream of repeated elements:

```
user> (take 9 (cycle suits))
(:clubs :diamonds :hearts :spades :clubs :diamonds :hearts :spades :clubs)
```

Comment: I also came up with (take 8 (cycle suits)). Seems to work, but I had to figure the "8" part out myself, without the help of a computer :-).

Answer (score 2):

(untested!)

```
(apply concat (repeat 2 suits))
```

will hopefully do the trick.

`concat` will of course concatenate 2 lists; `apply` can be used to smuggle a given function into the head position of an existing list for evaluation.

Comment: Fixed the function name (`assoc` -> `apply`).

Comment: Oh, how stupid of me. I use `apply` all the time, you'd think I'd know its name by now... Thanks for the fix!

Comment: `(doc replicate)` as of Clojure 1.7 says `DEPRECATED: Use 'repeat' instead.`

Answer (score 2):

A little experimentation with the REPL lead me to this solution:

```
user=> (def suits [:clubs :diamonds :hearts :spades])
#'user/suits
user=> suits
[:clubs :diamonds :hearts :spades]    
user=> (reduce concat (replicate 2 suits))
(:clubs :diamonds :hearts :spades :clubs :diamonds :hearts :spades)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(take (* 2 (count suits)) (cycle suits))
```